# Поиск фразы в массиве слов

Tags: c#, строки, работа-с-текстом

Весь мозг сломал, ничего в голове не приходит, как это реализовать программно на C#.

Comment: Разделить искомую фразу на слова и искать по словам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, примерно так. Можно еще добавить фильтр на дубликаты, но это уже сами :-)

```
        var pattern = "Автоматические ворота";
        var phrases = new []{ "Автоматические ворота", "автоматические ворота купить", "Автоматические ворота каталог всех", "Автоматические подъемные ворота","просто ворота" };
        var patternWords = pattern.Split(' ');

        var tempResult = phrases.Where(x => patternWords.All(p => x.Contains(p, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            .ToArray();

        Console.Write($"{pattern}");
        foreach (var phrase in tempResult)
        {
           var words = phrase.Split(' ')
               .Where(x => !patternWords.Any(p => x.Contains(p, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
               .ToArray();

           if(!words.Any())
               continue;

           Console.Write($", {string.Join(", ", words)}");
        }
```

Comment: Почти так, да. Вот только переменная "pattern" должна динамически обновляться. Вот цикл пробежался по массиву фраз и добавил все фразы через запятую в исходную, дальше цикл должен продолжить с той позиции, на которой закончились совпадение с первой(исходной фразой).

Вот целый список фраз:
Автоматические ворота
Автоматические ворота Doorhan
Автоматические ворота цена
Автоматические гаражные ворота
Автоматические подъемные ворота
Ворота для гаража
Ворота для гаража размер
Ворота для гаража цены

После автомат.ворот, дальше, проверить(по логике) должен "Ворота для гаража" и до конца.

Comment: @keinHerz Ну как был поставлен вопрос, такое решение я и показал. Но это я думаю вы сами сможете доделать, тут то какие сложности ;-)

Comment: Да вот уже вроде разобрался и вроде оно даже заработало!) Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Кстати, при попытке оставить в "Contains" значение "StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase", выдается ошибка, что нет такого аргумента у данного метода.

Comment: @keinHerz Да действительно, я тестровал в AppConsole .NET Core. Для  .NET Framework нужно написать вот так phrases.Where(x => patternWords.All(p => x.ToUpper().Contains(p.ToUpper())))   т.е. через ToUpper и то же самое для кода выделения оставшихся подстрок

Answer (score 2):

разбиваем на токены, пару раз группируем, получаем

```
string str = @"
Автоматические ворота
Автоматические ворота купить
Автоматические ворота каталог
Автоматические ворота цена
Где купить автоматические ворота
Автоматические гаражные ворота
Автоматические подъемные ворота
";

var lines = str.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Distinct().ToArray();

var linesByTokens = lines
    .ToDictionary(x => x,
        x => new HashSet<string>(x.ToLower().Split(new[] { " " },
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)));


var tokensCount = linesByTokens.Values
    .SelectMany(x => x).GroupBy(x => x)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

var topLine = linesByTokens
    .Where(x => x.Value.All(t => tokensCount[t] == lines.Length))
    .FirstOrDefault();

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (string.Compare(line, topLine.Key) == 0)
        Console.WriteLine($"{line}, {string.Join(", ", tokensCount.Keys.Except(linesByTokens[line]))}");
    else Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Вывод

```
Автоматические ворота, купить, каталог, цена, где, гаражные, подъемные
Автоматические ворота купить
Автоматические ворота каталог
Автоматические ворота цена
Где купить автоматические ворота
Автоматические гаражные ворота
Автоматические подъемные ворота
```

Comment: Вариант интересный, но ломается все при попытки добавить в этот список фразу, слова которой будут отличаться от всех остальных. К примеру: Вертикальные секционные ворота

Стоит добавить эту строчку в самый конец - все ломается и перестает работать.

Comment: Ну так вы не пояснили, по какиму принципу вы выбираете фразу `Автоматические ворота`. Я написал код по вашему примеру, если у вас другие примеры есть, то я не могу этого знать заранее - добавляйте их в вопрос, пишите по какому принципу вы поняли, что `Автоматические ворота` именно та фраза, которую надо изменить.

Comment: Я же написал "возьмем к примеру". Т.е, фразы которые я привел - это пример, чтобы понятно было чего я хочу.
Фразы эти находятся в файле и файл может изменяться, т.е, фразы могут как удаляться так и изменяться.
Суть такова: программа должна обработать все фразы и подставить к исходной, через запятую все слова которые есть в обрабатываемых фразах.
Слово "Автоматически" и "ворота" - это исходная фраза, то от чего код должен отталкиваться, если в последующих строках встречаются оба эти слова, то из этой строки надо удалить их и вставить в исходную все что осталось.

Comment: Она исхоная потому что первая? Или почему они исходная?